# Geometric mean of prime factors of all numbers up to n

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Through numerical calculations I have discovered that for any natural number $n \geq 2$, the geometric mean of the prime factors of all natural numbers $\leq n$ can be approximated well by $1.6653 \cdot n^{0.224}$. Is there a number-theoretic explanation for why this is a good approximation?

Comment: I can't seem to confirm your approximation. Could you please define a formula for how you're calculating "the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of the prime factors of all natural numbers $\le n$"?

Comment: $\Omega(n) :=$ number of prime factors of $n$. $f(n) := n!^{1/\Sigma_{i=2}^n \Omega(n)}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe you meant $(n!)^{\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=2}^n \Omega(i)}}$ ($\Omega(i)$ vs $\Omega(n)$).

Comment: Have you also investigated $\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\prod\limits_{p|k} p\right)\right){}^{\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \nu(k)}}$ where $\nu(k)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $k$ which is closer to my original interpretation?

Comment: The $\log\log n=$ constant strikes again! (in fact no, $\log n/\log\log n$).

Comment: So, primes without repetition? for $n=12$, you put $6$ in the product, not $12$? Then I think you're taking $n$-th roots of the numbers tabulated at https://oeis.org/A048803

Comment: @GerryMyerson The OP clarified in a comment that he is interested in $n!^{1/\Sigma_{m=2}^n \Omega(m)}$. Here $\Omega(m)$ denotes the sum of exponents in the prime power decomposition of $m$, although the conclusion in my post would not change if we replaced $\Omega(m)$ by $\omega(m)$, which is the number of distinct prime factors of $m$. See https://oeis.org/A001222 and https://oeis.org/A001221

Answer (score 18):

What you experience is the "law of small numbers". The logarithm of the geometric mean in question is
$$\frac{\log n!}{\sum_{m=1}^n\Omega(m)}\sim\frac{n\log n}{n\log\log n}=\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}.$$
In other words, the geometric mean in question is $n^{(1+o(1))/\log\log n}$, which for large $n$ is smaller than $n^{0.001}$.

**Numerical calculation performed by SAGE.** For $n=10^7$, the geometric mean is about $54.2187$, while $1.6653 \cdot n^{0.224}$ is about $61.5874$.